# Android Iptables: Can´t drop port

Tags: android, iptables

I try to `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 5228 -j DROP` but it comes to failure messages:

`FIX ME! implement getprotobyname() bionic/libc/bionic/stubs.c:378`

I have an rooted device and busybox on it. Strange is that if I see the rules list of iptables this port is in it. I´m not sure does it work? What is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a known bug:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=558415

It lists workarounds if you're interested.

Comment: thanks. It seems to be necessary to re-implement binaries. Do you maybe know some other possibilities to make iptables run without this failure?

Comment: I get the same error when running against adb. It is something that google will have to fix in their Android OS release. If you are doing this in your application, you could catch that exception and do your own error handling... I haven't messed too much around with IP tables on Android so I can't really give you advice on this. It does work on my Fedora 14 box though...

Answer (score 0):

Use protocol numbers (`-p 6`) instead of names (`-p tcp`):

`iptables -A OUTPUT -p 6 --sport 5228 -j DROP`

See this answer for more info:
[getprotobyname error iptables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331699/getprotobyname-error-iptables/18385413#18385413)