# getprotobyname error iptables

Tags: android

I have android with iptables support on a rooted device.

I seem to get this error, anyone have any idea why?

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 8000 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

```
FIX ME! implement getprotobyname() bionic/libc/bionic/stubs.c:378
```

Comment: This is a known issue, as you would find out if you a did a web search on iptables and the error message before asking here.  If this is actually critical rather than tangential you would need to patch iptables with the unsupported function or use it in a way that avoids the need for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android uses Bionic libc, which is a really minimal libc that is missing lots of things. That error message  is saying that `getprotobyname()` is not implemented in Bionic libc. `iptables` seems to run the command anyway when this error is triggered, but my guess is that its ignoring the `-p tcp` part and just setting the rule for all protocols.

Luckily that function is not essential to working with iptables. `getprotobyname()` just converts protocol names like tcp to a number (tcp == 6). You can find those numbers here: http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xml

Use the protocol number instead `-p 6` to eliminate the error message:

`iptables -A INPUT -p 6 -i eth0 --dport 8000 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Tried this, now I get "FIX ME! implement getprotobynumber() bionic/libc/bionic/stubs.c:384"

Comment: @Dakkaron perhaps you are using an old Android version that does not even have `getprotobynumber()` implemented?  In that case, it seems like your only option is to omit `-p` and set rules for all protocols.

Comment: I'm also getting `getprotobynumber` error on Android 4.1.2

Answer (score 6):

You can type 6 instead of tcp.

**iptables -A INPUT -p 6** (instead of iptables -A INPUT -p tcp )

http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xml

Answer (score 1):

On some devices this may be just a warning but the rule will be OK.
Check that the rule appears using iptables -L INPUT -nv
and then try it.

Comment: `iptables` seems to run the command anyway when this error is triggered, but my guess is that its ignoring the `-p tcp` part and just setting the rule for all protocols.  Use protocol numbers if including the protocol in the rule is essential.